# ajax success data assignment to variables with data[0] is undefined

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to select data from a database in javascript code using ajax which calls a php script with a mysql query. The pgp code is working correctly, as I can view the ajax success results with an alert. But when I try to assign the data to variables, they show in the Console as undefined or NaN. Here is my code:

```
    function zoomBldg() {

        bldgId = document.getElementById("bldgzoom").value;

        var bldgStreetAddress,zoomLat,zoomLng,bldgDescription,bldgDefaultPic,zoomCenter;

        console.log('bldgId',bldgId);

        $.ajax({
            url: "getBldgInfoWajaxGETtest.php", 
            type: "POST",             
            data: {bldgId : bldgId},
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function(data)
            {
                alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                bldgStreetAddress = data[0];
                zoomLat = data[1];
                zoomLng = data[2];
                bldgDefaultPic = data[3];

            },
            error: function (request, status, error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });

        zoomLat = parseFloat(zoomLat);
        zoomLng = parseFloat(zoomLng);
        zoomCenter = {lat:zoomLat, lng:zoomLng};

        console.log('bldgId',bldgId);
        console.log('bldgStreetAddress',bldgStreetAddress);
        console.log('zoomLat',zoomLat);
        console.log('zoomLng',zoomLng);

    }
```

The results that appear in the alert is:

[{"0":"50 Fremont Street","1":"37.790505","2":"-122.397259","3":null,"building_address":"50 Fremont Street","latitude":"37.790505","longitude":"-122.397259","default_pic":null}]

The results in the Console are:

bldgId 17
bldgId 17
bldgStreetAddress undefined
zoomLat NaN
zoomLng NaN

I copied the data[0] etc code from an example online, but I am not too familiar with json so I'm not sure why that isn't working.

Comment: The bldg street address is set to data[0]. Do you have a 0 key in your json?

Comment: You set `zoomCenter ` (and others variables) before your success callback. Move those lines at the end of your callback success function.

Comment: adeneo please remove the exact duplicate. The OP is asking about why the code is not working. Not about how to return the response of a async call.

Comment: @adeneo please read my comment above.

Comment: @AskingQuestions - You've missed the point completely, `$.ajax` is **asynchronous**, one *can not* put data into variables inside the success handler, and access them outside it, because the code outside executes before the code inside the `success` function, because ...... wait for it .... **it's asynchronous** !

Comment: *face palm* I did, I will fix my answer. Thank you for responding.

Comment: @AskingQuestions - no problem !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Understand the code your copying and pasting. Learn how json works and what `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify` do.

Look at your json structure.
The information is in an array.
so `data` is an array. Each key of the object is a string not a integer.

`data[0]["1"]`

You also have the success function being called later on. Thus the values would not be set. To fix this I would do any code that needs the values in or from the success callback.

```
            success: function(data)
            {
                alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                bldgStreetAddress = data[0]["0"];
                zoomLat = data[0]["1"];
                zoomLng = data[0]["2"];
                bldgDefaultPic = data[0]["3"];

                zoomLat = parseFloat(zoomLat);
                zoomLng = parseFloat(zoomLng);
                zoomCenter = {lat:zoomLat, lng:zoomLng};

    console.log('bldgId',bldgId);
    console.log('bldgStreetAddress',bldgStreetAddress);
    console.log('zoomLat',zoomLat);
    console.log('zoomLng',zoomLng);

            },
```